# Mongoose - 2dsphere index - howto

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongoose

I am working with Node.js.How can I configure a 2dsphere index for a Polygon on the schema of Mongoose?

I have tried with it:

```
  location_2dsphere: {
      type: { type: String }
      , coordinates: []
  },
```

But it doesn't work!

Answer (score 2):

this is how you do it

```
location_2dsphere: {
  'type': { type: String },
    coordinates: []
  }
```

So the key thing is to make the first `type` to be `'type'`

Then remember to create a `2dsphere` index on your field!

In Mongoose, when you want to name a field as `type` or any other reserved field, just force string conversion by using the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

On top level:

```
db.collections.<yourcollection>.createIndex({ <location_field> : "2dsphere" })
```

where `db = mongoose.connection`

Notice there is a "collections" property before collection itself. If it's not working, check db object in console.log:

```
console.log(db)
```