# Mongoose geoNear maxDistance Results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using node.js and mongoose. I have 4 objects in my db with `lng/lat` coordinates. In real life, those positions are within 1 or 2 miles of each other.

```
module.exports.locationsListByDistance = function(req, res) {
    var lng = parseFloat(req.query.lng);
    var lat = parseFloat(req.query.lat);
    var point = {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [lng, lat]
    };
    var geoOptions =  {
        spherical: true,
        maxDistance: 20 / 3963,
        num: 10
    };
    Loc.geoNear(point, geoOptions, function(err, results, stats) {
        var locations;
        console.log('Geo Results', results);
        console.log('Geo stats', stats);
        if (err) {
            console.log('geoNear error:', err);
            sendJsonResponse(res, 404, err);
        } else {
            locations = buildLocationList(req, res, results, stats);
            sendJsonResponse(res, 200, locations);
        }
    });
};
```

This is my code. When `Loc.geoNear` is run, in the callback function `results` returns an empty array. The only way I can get it to actually return objects is by setting `maxDistance: 2500` and it will then retrieve 2 objects with ridiculous *distances*.

Now obviously, 2500 is a huge number and this makes zero sense. I need within 20 miles of each other, that's why I convert to radians via `20 / 3963`, but the resulting `maxDistance` is so small that mongo return nothing. Any ideas?

**EDIT 1** 
(Adding a document)

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5714204af42b2b9004313d7c"
    },
    "name": "Starcups",
    "address": "125 High Street, Reading, RG6 1PS",
    "rating": 3,
    "facilities": [
        "Hot drinks",
        "Food",
        "Premium wifi"
    ],
    "coords": {
        "lng": -84.135166,
        "lat": 34.190996
    },
    "openingTimes": [
        {
            "days": "Monday - Friday",
            "opening": "7:00am",
            "closing": "7:00pm",
            "closed": false
        },
        {
            "days": "Saturday",
            "opening": "8:00am",
            "closing": "5:00pm",
            "closed": false
        },
        {
            "days": "Sunday",
            "closed": true
        }
    ],
    "reviews": [
        {
            "author": "Kenny Hall",
            "rating": 5,
            "timestamp": "13 April 2016",
            "reviewText": "What a great place. I can't say enough good things about it."
        },
        {
            "author": "Charlie Chaplin",
            "rating": 3,
            "timestamp": "16 June 2015",
            "reviewText": "It was okay. Coffee wasn't great, but the wifi was fast."
        }
    ]
}
```

**EDIT 2** (Adding the model/schema)

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    author: String,
    rating: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 5
    },
    reviewText: String,
    createdOn: {
        type: Date,
        "default": Date.now
    }
});

var openingTimeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    days: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    opening: String,
    closing: String,
    closed: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true
    }
});

var locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    address: String,
    rating: {
        type: Number,
        "default": 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 5
    },
    facilities: [String],
    // Always store coordinates longitude, latitude order
    coords: {
        type: [Number],
        index: '2dsphere'
    },
    openingTimes: [openingTimeSchema],
    reviews: [reviewSchema]
});

mongoose.model('Location', locationSchema);
```

Comment: What type of index do you have? 2d or 2dsphere?

Comment: Also please post sample MongoDB documents

Comment: @Saleem it's a 2dsphere. And I'll edit the post with a document.

Comment: see my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36646641/mongodb-geonear-distance-is-different-than-google-maps-distance/36648669#36648669 and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36712676/moongose-geonear-aggregation-add-basic-query-options/36717384#36717384 see if it helps

Comment: @Saleem it's nice to know the differences, thanks. But Mongod still returns unrealistic values if you check my comments below to Anonymous-SOS answer.

Comment: I suspect problem is with your document structure. See my post below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So originally I was thinking the MongoDB was working in *radians*, so I've been trying to do all these conversion for that. But after more research here, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/geoNear/#dbcmd.geoNear , it says that if `spherical: true` then it uses meters.

So I simply wrote a new conversion method so when I set `maxDistance` in *km* in the query, I'd convert it and use *m* instead, now everything works great!

```
var meterConversion = (function() {
    var mToKm = function(distance) {
        return parseFloat(distance / 1000);
    };
    var kmToM = function(distance) {
        return parseFloat(distance * 1000);
    };
    return {
        mToKm : mToKm,
        kmToM : kmToM
    };
})();

/* GET list of locations */
module.exports.locationsListByDistance = function(req, res) {
    var lng = parseFloat(req.query.lng);
    var lat = parseFloat(req.query.lat);
    var maxDistance = parseFloat(req.query.maxDistance);
    if ((!lng && lng !== 0) || (!lat && lat !== 0) || !maxDistance) {
        console.log('locationsListByDistance missing params');
        sendJsonResponse(res, 404, {
            "message" : "lng, lat and maxDistance query parameters are all required"
        });
        return;
    }
    var point = {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [lng, lat]
    };
    var geoOptions =  {
        spherical: true,
        maxDistance: meterConversion.kmToM(maxDistance),
        num: 10
    };
    Loc.geoNear(point, geoOptions, function(err, results, stats) {
        var locations;
        console.log('Geo Results', results);
        console.log('Geo stats', stats);
        if (err) {
            console.log('geoNear error:', err);
            sendJsonResponse(res, 404, err);
        } else {
            locations = buildLocationList(req, res, results, stats);
            sendJsonResponse(res, 200, locations);
        }
    });
};

var buildLocationList = function(req, res, results, stats) {
    var locations = [];
    results.forEach(function(doc) {
        locations.push({
            distance: meterConversion.mToKm(doc.dis), 
            name: doc.obj.name,
            address: doc.obj.address,
            rating: doc.obj.rating,
            facilities: doc.obj.facilities,
            _id: doc.obj._id
        });
    });
    return locations;
};
```

Special thanks to @Saleem and others who helped me arrive at a solution.

Comment: Writing a function to convert "m" to "km" and vice versa looks for me like an overkill. Simply do `distance: doc.dis / 1000`

Answer (score 3):

I suspect issue with your document structure. 2dsphere expects document in [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html) format.

Your document should look like

```
"coords" : {
    "type" : "Point",
    "coordinates" : [ 
        -84.135166,
        34.190996
    ]
}
```

Let's say your document is:

```
{
  "name": "Starcups",
  "address": "125 High Street, Reading, RG6 1PS",
  "rating": 3,
  "facilities": [
    "Hot drinks",
    "Food",
    "Premium wifi"
  ],
  "location": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      -84.135166,
      34.190996
    ]
  },
  "openingTimes": [
    {
      "days": "Monday - Friday",
      "opening": "7:00am",
      "closing": "7:00pm",
      "closed": false
    },
    {
      "days": "Saturday",
      "opening": "8:00am",
      "closing": "5:00pm",
      "closed": false
    },
    {
      "days": "Sunday",
      "closed": true
    }
  ],
  "reviews": [
    {
      "author": "Kenny Hall",
      "rating": 5,
      "timestamp": "13 April 2016",
      "reviewText": "What a great place. I can't say enough good things about it."
    },
    {
      "author": "Charlie Chaplin",
      "rating": 3,
      "timestamp": "16 June 2015",
      "reviewText": "It was okay. Coffee wasn't great, but the wifi was fast."
    }
  ]
}
```

and you are trying to find all documents with in 5000 meters from point `[ -84.105146 , 34.190096 ]`

```
db.collection.aggregate(
[
    {
        '$geoNear': {
            'near': {
                'type': 'Point',
                'coordinates': [ -84.105146 , 34.190096 ]
            },
            'spherical': true, 
            'distanceField': 'dist',
            'maxDistance': 5000         
        }
    }
]);
```

Query above will return document posted above as it falls with in 5000 meter radius provided that you have created `2dsphere` index on `location`

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("57327c856b37a28ec9221392"), 
    "name" : "Starcups", 
    "address" : "125 High Street, Reading, RG6 1PS", 
    "rating" : 3.0, 
    "facilities" : [
        "Hot drinks", 
        "Food", 
        "Premium wifi"
    ], 
    "location" : {
        "type" : "Point", 
        "coordinates" : [
            -84.135166, 
            34.190996
        ]
    }, 
    "openingTimes" : [
        {
            "days" : "Monday - Friday", 
            "opening" : "7:00am", 
            "closing" : "7:00pm", 
            "closed" : false
        }, 
        {
            "days" : "Saturday", 
            "opening" : "8:00am", 
            "closing" : "5:00pm", 
            "closed" : false
        }, 
        {
            "days" : "Sunday", 
            "closed" : true
        }
    ], 
    "reviews" : [
        {
            "author" : "Kenny Hall", 
            "rating" : 5.0, 
            "timestamp" : "13 April 2016", 
            "reviewText" : "What a great place. I can't say enough good things about it."
        }, 
        {
            "author" : "Charlie Chaplin", 
            "rating" : 3.0, 
            "timestamp" : "16 June 2015", 
            "reviewText" : "It was okay. Coffee wasn't great, but the wifi was fast."
        }
    ], 
    "dist" : 2766.0558990550367
}
```

Comment: In this, it looks like *lat* is before *lng*, is that right?

Comment: my lat is 34 and long is -84. So that'd be `"coordinates" : [ -84.1401930, 34.2073200 ]`

Comment: In my model/schema, I have `coords: {
        type: [Number],
        index: '2dsphere'
    }` do I also need to change that? Because I changed the documents in my database to the formatting you posted above, and my `geoNear` queries were still returning a distance in the thousands.

Comment: I edited my original post. At the bottom is my schema. So I need to change part of it, correct?

Comment: See my updated post. hopefully it will answer your question. for how to create 2d index see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17485036/mongoose-2dsphere-index-howto

Comment: Thanks for the update!  My only concern is that `db.collection.aggregate()` function, is that code that would go in node.js? Or is it a console command?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111584/discussion-between-saleem-and-kenny).

Answer (score 0):

Check for the `distanceMultiplier` in your mongod configuration:

> You may also use the distanceMultiplier option to the geoNear to convert radians in the mongod process, rather than in your application code. See distance multiplier.

Comment: I've used the `distanceMultiplier` with a value of 3963 for miles and used no controller logic to convert radians, but it gave similar feedback.

Comment: OK. I still think it is in meters, that's why you get good results with 2500 and above.

Comment: with no `maxDistance` or `distanceMultiplier`, the db returns all objects and they have a value of 2,000+ (ie 2386.126, 2488.271, etc..). So despite all I've read about Mongo working in radians, it seems it's working in some other unit.

Comment: distanceMultiplier is used only when using 2d index.

Comment: Look at this [example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/geoNear/#specify-a-mindistance-and-maxdistance). It uses spherical and the distance is in meters.